# PWA Angular: tapping text on textarea with keyboard open causes focus lose

Tags: android, html, css, angular, progressive-web-apps

I'm encountering a peculiar issue while working on my Progressive Web App (PWA) for Android, and I could use some assistance or insights from the community.

The problem I'm facing involves the keyboard closing unexpectedly when a user interacts with a textarea in my PWA. Specifically, while typing or trying to select text within the textarea, touching the text seems to cause the keyboard to suddenly close. This behavior disrupts the editing process, as **the page receives the tap as if the user touched an element that would be there if the keyboard were not displayed.**

I've tried a few troubleshooting steps such as preventing the propagation of touch events within the textarea to stop the keyboard from closing involuntarily. However, the issue persists, and I'm seeking guidance or suggestions on how to resolve this.

Has anyone else encountered a similar problem before? If so, how did you manage to address it?

Any advice, workaround, or insight would be greatly appreciated. If you've encountered a similar situation or have ideas on how to handle this, please share your thoughts!

NOTE: this behavior didn't happen in iOS, it is working fine there.

Thank you in advance for any help or guidance you can provide.

Comment: It seems that changing "display" property of the manifest.webmanifest file to "standalone" solved the issue. I'll let you know after some days of real users testing.

Comment: what was the value of "display" property prior to the change?